# IsPostBack always false after button click

Tags: asp.net, postback, ispostback

On my pages onLoad() function I'm disabling all controls on the page in the following manner

```
var form = document.getElementById("form1");
var elements = form.elements;
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    elements[i].disabled = true;
}
document.getElementById('btnReactivate').disabled = false;
```

I need one button on the page enabled (btnReactivate above).  The problem I'm having is that anytime I click the button and step into the Page_Load event Page.IsPostback is always false And the onclick event in the code behind also doesn't fire. The button is created

```
<asp:Button runat="server"  ID="btnReactivate" Text="btnReactivate" onclick="btnReactivate_Click" width="80px" meta:resourcekey="btnReactivateResource1"  />
```

and the event handler as so

```
protected void btnReactivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
```

It's might be also worth mentioning that I've tried disabling the forms elements in a few different ways including just looping through in Input controls rather than all elements

Comment: The problem is that onclick always uses a full postback. Have you tried to put your form into an update panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this happens because disabled controls are not posted back to the server (thus preventing detection of the postback).

You should make the controls `Readonly`. Or re-enable them client-side just before posting.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled

> Disabled controls cannot be successful.

and, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly

> Read-only elements may be successful.

Comment: But since I'm not disabling the btnReactivate button does your comment above apply?

Comment: Actually I tried re-enabling client-side and it does seemed to have worked :)